# GraphQL query fields that matches with Sequelize Query

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, graphql, graphql-js

I have a simple scenario here.

I have a People sequelize model that has 5 fields: firstName, lastName, id, city, and zipCode. I also have a GraphQL Object that has the same fields.

Every time I do a GraphQL query, for example:

```
{
   people(id:123){
    firstName
    lastName
}
```

Sequelize sends a SQL statement like this:

```
SELECT `firstName`, `lastName`, `id`, `city`, `zipCode` FROM `People` WHERE `People`.`id` = 123;
```

Is it possible that I can make Sequelize sends a SQL statement that is like this:

```
SELECT `firstName`, `lastName` FROM `People` WHERE `People`.`id` = 123;
```

Basically what I want is that the SQL statement does not select any extra columns that I don't want.

This is my resolve function in GraphQL query object:

```
resolve: function (root, args) {
   return Db.models.People.findAll({ where: args });
}
```

Comment: You need to use `attributes` on the sequelize query, [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#attributes)  is the documentation

Comment: Great question I am also looking for an answer here. @Ellebkey it's not possible get fields in query.

Comment: I should have been more specific, if you want to use an argument for the fields that you get as response you have to apply to `attributes` like this `Db.models.People.findAll({ where: {}, attributes: args })` where `args` is an array of strings with the fields. The `where` statement is the same as SQL for filter your query.

Comment: @YiYaoNg did you ever find a solution?